# Which one to use? grid.sort vs searchtools.sort

Tags: joomla-3.x, best-practices

I have been looking at why column sort orders wouldn't change in the front list view of my component and found by changing

```
        <?php echo HtmlHelper::_('searchtools.sort',  'JGRID_HEADING_ID', 'invlines.id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

to

```
        <?php echo HtmlHelper::_('grid.sort',  'JGRID_HEADING_ID', 'invlines.id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
```

that it all started working and that has set me off trying to understanding what i should be using.

Not that I can find any documentation to support this but it seems to me looking at Joomla document and examples that `/libraries/cms/html/grid.php` is mostly used in the front end examples while libraries`/cms/html/searchtools.php` is used in the back end in the examples and tutorials I have found.

`seachtools.sort` also seems to be more modern using layouts to render the html.

Is anyone able to confirm this is the case or provide some explanation of when to use one over the other?

Update...

Looking closer at the code behind the two options I can see that `grid.sort` will produce this html

```
<a href="#" onclick="Joomla.tableOrdering('orders.creditor_id','asc','');return false;" class="hasPopover" title="" data-content="Select to sort by this column" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Supplier Id">Supplier Id</a>
```

and `grid.sort` uses this pieces of JS to update the two hidden fields in the form, `filter_order` and `filter_order_dir`

```
Joomla.tableOrdering = function( order, dir, task, form ) {
    if ( typeof form  === 'undefined' ) {
        form = document.getElementById( 'adminForm' );
    }

    form.filter_order.value = order;
    form.filter_order_Dir.value = dir;
    Joomla.submitform( task, form );
};
```

While `searchtools.grid` creates the following html

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="js-stools-column-order hasPopover" data-order="invlines.invoice_num" data-direction="ASC" data-name="Purchase Invoice #" title="" data-content="Select to sort by this column" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Purchase Invoice #">
Purchase Invoice #</a>
```

and from there it uses the `/media/jui/js/jquery.searchtools.js` to pick up when the column heading has been clicked and which way it should be sorted.
From there I am not exactly sure how or where that info is stored when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with `grid.sort` you have basic ordering and `searchtools.sort` you have more options such as search field, search by published items, unpublished items, trashed items and more. Both can be used in the backend but `searchtools.sort` is more recommended since you have more options.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try and answer my question. I don't believe the search field or other filter boxes are related to the searchtools.sort functionality.

Comment: I mean i believe it offers the possibility of adding a costumize filter for ordering and search as far as i know. I may be wrong though. But you can try to figure it out here:  with`grid.sort` https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_decorations_to_the_backend#admin.2Fviews.2Fhelloworlds.2Ftmpl.2Fdefault.php and using `searchtools.grid ` https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_front-end_form#admin.2Fviews.2Fhelloworlds.2Ftmpl.2Fdefault.php

Comment: By the way, to use `searchtools.grid` you have to do some modifications. Check the above link out.